# How to get the count of elements in database using delphi XE8

Tags: database, delphi

I am trying to make an e-mail sender with Delphi. I have database with statuses and emails and I need to get the number of elements in my database so that I can make a for loop. This is part of my code:

```
procedure TForm1.bDataBaseClick(Sender: TObject);
      var
        i : integer;
    begin
      FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
      FDConnection1.Open();
      //FDQuery1.ExecSQL('UPDATE Vasko '
                               //+' SET BatchNumber = 112233 '
                               //+' WHERE StatusOfProd = 4');
      //FDQuery1.ExecSQL('select * from Vasko');
      for i := 0 to FDQuery1.ComponentCount - 1 do
      showmessage('hello');

      FDConnection1.Commit;
      FDConnection1.Close();
end;
```

For now I just want to make the loop that shows message several times. I think that I have mistake in this line:

```
 for i := 0 to FDQuery1.ComponentCount - 1 do
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That property is not what you [expect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TComponent.ComponentCount). What you are interested in is [naviating datasets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Navigating_Datasets).

Comment: There's more mistakes, but you might be looking for `FDQuery1.RecordCount` (just be aware that FireDAC has a few modes that affect what this property returns).

Comment: Why do you need to know the count in order to iterate over the query result?

Comment: well I have a database with e-mails and I need to send e-mails if status is 0 for example so I must iterate all in my opinion.

Comment: Then you should use a loop like WHILE not FDQuery1.EOF DO... and in the loop use FDQuery1.next at the end to advance to the next record.

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question is why you feel that you need to know the number of items in order to iterate over them. If you would do some research you'd find that all the examples of iterating over data do not require the count to be known up front.

Comment: I made it @DavidHeffernan. I used 'End of file' and some functions.

Comment: @Kostadin The whole point of a database is that it has powerful tools to manage data - it sounds like you think you need to reinvent things that databases can do for you.  If you need to select all records where `StatusOfProd = 0` just do `SELECT * FROM Vasko WHERE StatusOfProd = 0`.  You don't need to `SELECT *` and iterate over the entire database to find the data yourself.  That would be painfully slow and inefficient.

Comment: thank you @J... well I make something but now if I want to change data in the data base I get the error that database is closed.....